# What is the solution of "Can't move multiple source file" in Android Studio 3.6?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

When I try to move multiple files by selecting all it shows like below, but I can move a single file at a time. Can any one give me the solution?

[[image: Can't move from multiple source files]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKAX8.png)

Comment: If this is a refactor, that limitation was in 3.5 as well. And, I agree, it is annoying. However... what is your question?

Comment: @CommonsWare i think the question is clearly described above: 
how to solve this annoying antiFeature? :)

Comment: @android51130: Yes, and that edit was made about 9 hours after my comment.

Comment: @CommonsWare hands up(sorry), waiting for solution..

Comment: @android51130: AFAIK, the solution is: hope that JetBrains and/or Google allow more flexibility here in Android Studio 4.0 or beyond.

Comment: Here's the issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147871176

Comment: Find the source file and change it in at Folder level outside the IDE.